# Configurar git em uma hospedagem compartilhada

Tags: git, bitbucket

Tenho uma hospedagem compartilhada na hostgator e na descrição dos planos vi que cliente git é aceito. Entrei em contato com o suporte da Hostgator para entender melhor sobre detalhes do cliente git que eles falam, eis a resposta:

"A diferença entre o Git server e Git Cliente, encontra-se na funcionalidade, onde um cliente Git é apenas um usuário utilizando servidores externos.

Já o Git server, seria utilizado para criar um repositório e fornecer a outros usuários, como não é permitido a utilização de servidores compartilhados como repositório, não é possível realizar o procedimento em planos P,M,Business,Plus e Revendas."

A questão é, tenho um repositório privado no bitbucket, eu consigo configurar o servidor para que ao fazer um push na minha maquina local, automaticamente as alterações são salvas no repositório e replicadas no site?

Comment: Eu não entendi o seu objetivo! Você tem o repositório no Bitbucket... E nos servidores onde rodam a sua aplicação você quer configurar clientes Git para baixarem o código é isso?

Answer (score 2):

Ola, camarada. já tive o mesmo problema quando trabalhava com gitlab e usava heroku. 
Ainda não vi nenhuma forma para resolver isso se não: 
-Criar ou sincronizar seu projeto com o repositório remoto(no seu caso user-name@your-domain.com:public_html/project-name)
-neste caso tera dois ramos de desenvolvimento- origin e do repositorio remoto.

Veja esse artigo, mostra como fazer isso em minimos detalhes: http://www.arlocarreon.com/blog/git/push-git-repo-into-shared-hosting-account-like-hostgator/

ou esse:
https://medium.com/29-degrees/setup-a-git-repository-on-a-shared-hostgator-account-7a7e306ef66f

Espero ter ajudado...

Comment: Elton, poderia trazer a explicação dos procedimentos para a sua resposta? Aqui preferimos que as respostas não dependam de links externos, que podem deixar de funcionar. Obrigado.